# Delete identical files

Tags: linux, diff, unlink

I'm able to find all identical files in 2 directories with the following command:

```
diff -srq sub1/ sub2/ | grep identical
```

Is it possible to delete founds one easily, so I only have the not identical files in both directories?

Comment: This is not a programming question, and thus off-topic here. Have it [moved over](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) to https://unix.stackexchange.com. Also make sure to do some research before asking; this has probably already been answered somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is off-topic on this site, but I'll answer. Since your question is somewhat unclear to me, whether you want to delete all identical files, or only one of the files, so I'll give you both options.

This deletes all matched files:

```
diff -srq sub1/ sub2/ | grep identical | xargs rm
```

This deletes only first matched file:

```
diff -srq sub1/ sub2/ | grep identical | head -1 | xargs rm
```

Note, I haven't tested this, but at least you have a starting point.